# Configure Laptop as Mysql server

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

I want to ask, How to configure my phpMyAdmin, where is my database, which i want to access from my Java application when i start it on different laptop on different network. App work great on my Laptop, when i use localhost instead my external IP address  for example 88.88.88.88. Problem isn't in the code. I'm stuck in this for a week. I configure my router and the problem is not there.

Comment: I use MySQL on XAMPP

Comment: You question is vague and unclear. Please take the time to revise it, there is an `edit` link below it for that. Try to explain better what your actual setup is, what is working, what is not working. If you want to get good answers, then you certainly should invest into a good question.

Comment: @arkascha is right. Please explain your setup more.

Comment: I make a few changes: In the my.ini i comment the lines: #bind-address="0.0.0.0"
# bind-address = ::1 and # bind-address = 127.0.0.1 . I make users, a lot of them with different setup and nothing work for now.  I try this:                                                                                 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: and it show:  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: Does your application reside on the same laptop on which MySQL is running? Or your application is running different system and mysql on laptop or other way around?

Comment: And the ping is Success 0 lost

Comment: The app is on my other laptop and connect him to other network. My personal Laptop where is MySQL is running on my Home network. I just want to run the app outside my Home Network, for example if i give it to you, you should be able to view the data from the  queries

Comment: Got it. Now from any laptop outside your network try to ping your laptop IP address. I bet you won't be able to ping it. The reason is that your laptop which is running MySQL is running on internal network. In order for application to reach out to your MySQL laptop, both have to be either on same network or somehow make it publicly accessible.

Comment: Actually the ping is fine- 0 lost. I open the app on the other Laptop but on same network with Mysql, and still dont work.

Comment: @losif Petrov, so when your accessing to `mysql server ip` what is the result? is firewall allowing for inbound ?

Comment: Give me: This site can’t be reached. When i accesing from outside the network from different one. I do this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh168549(v=nav.90).aspx                                                                      but still the same. Will try to use MySQL workbench to see what will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first ensure that the server on which Java application is running, is able to ping the server which is hosting MySQL server. Then allow remote access to server.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It is better practice that you create a new username in MySQL, assign access to only one database which will be used by the Java application.

Comment: You want to read about what the term "server" actually refers to. It is _not_ a system, but a specific service offered on a system. MySQL is a server. There is the apache http server. The system these servers are executed on is _not_ a "server".

Comment: Makes sense. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thank. That line solve my problem. I change XAMPP MySQL with MySQL Workbench and using this line of code, the problem is solved and now i'm able to use my app outside the MySQL network. :)